# How to handle neutral characters like space, dot with LTR and RTL words

Tags: bidi

I have a textbox on my html page along with title="Please enter any word(s)."

**Issue:** When user enters some arabic or Urdu (Right to Left) words, the textbox tooltip shows as ".(Please enter any word(s"

How to fix such issues?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** A neutral character between two strongly typed characters that have the same directional type will also assume that directionality. So a neutral character between two RTL characters will be treated as a RTL character itself, and will have the effect of extending the directional run.

**References:** http://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics
http://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/
http://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/#whattodo

**Suggested Solution:** Override the bidi algorithm by appending bidi marker after the neutral characters like dot. In our case, append ‎ after the search field title. Eg: title="Please enter search term(s).&lrm;‎"